# Custom domain + receiving at SES

Tags: amazon-web-services, amazon-simple-email-service

I'm wondering if anyone has done the below before, the documentation is not apparent since this is sort of combining two configurations on AWS...

I use SES for receiving mail more than sending it.  It's a pretty good service to use as a catch-all for domains without multiple users, which works fine for... say, small non-profits in which one person answers all of the incoming email from a few public addresses.  I have all incoming mail dumped into an S3 bucket and the SES active rule set triggers a Lambda function to parse the recipient of the incoming mail and forward it to predefined gmail addresses.

However, I have one account that wishes to send out fundraising mails to newsletter subs, and of course they'll want to buy their own IP from AWS for this purpose, to include DMARC and PTR records for minimizing their losses to spam filters.

SES has the capability to do this, by setting a 'custom domain' for your outgoing SES email.  The catch is, by going through the motions to set this up I notice that SES designates the incoming MX you must use to feedback-smtp.(region).amazonses.com rather than the inbound-smtp.(region).amazon.ses.com that normal receiving at SES requires.

Can these two configurations (receiving as well as custom domain for outgoing) co-exist? Or does feedback-smtp.(region).amazonses.com get handled differently somehow?

Anyone done this before?

Answer (score 0):

You don't need to worry about the Feedback MX address.
In SES, you can't have Custom mail from for naked domain (e.g: example.com)
You need to use something like mail.example.com and publish the MX record as feedback-smtp.(region).amazonses.com, this won't affect your incoming emails.

To comply with DMARC using that, you need to make sure that aspf is set to relaxed.
https://docs.aws.amazon.com/ses/latest/DeveloperGuide/dmarc.html